# libpng error in application compiled by bazel

Tags: bazel

I am using ubuntu 17.04 to compile tensorflow c++ program related to alexnet that use libpng.

libpng warning: Application was compiled with png.h from libpng-1.6.23
libpng warning: Application is running with png.c from libpng-1.2.53
libpng error: Incompatible libpng version in application and library

When I run the program I get error of uncompatible libpng error and the program halts with segmentation fault.

What is the reason behind it and how can I solve it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you compiled your application with libpng-1.6.23 and at runtime your app tried to use libpng-1.2.53.  The two versions are not compatible, so you get a segfault.

There are two possibilities here:

- If you're running your program on the same machine you're building on, you have two versions of libpng installed.  Use a tool (like `slocate`) to find the versions and uninstall one of them.
- If you're running your program on a different machine(s) than the one you built on. Upgrade libpng to 1.6.23 on those machines.